# Is it possible to install several instances of Apache or to have several php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, configuration

Well... the title explains almost everything... Is it possible to install several instances of Apache or to have several php.ini?

I have several customers in my server with different requirements and I would need either I install 2 apaches or have 2 php.ini for these configurations.

In case it is possible, how can i choose the configuration depending on the URL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the requirements which differs from the two clients? I ask because configurations can be set for different domeins in the same webservers: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? There may be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod-fastcgi or mod-fcgi, which run PHP as a separate standalone daemon. Then, for each website, you can define a separate user and php.ini config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do virtual hosts which you could base on the domain used to access the server. In the configuration of each virtual host you could customize things for your client needs.  You can google "apache2 virtual hosts" for the documentation, but here is an example of a virtual server:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/vhosts/example.com/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/vhosts/example.com/www>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

            php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/www
            php_admin_value disable_functions exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

            php_admin_value session.referer_check example.com
            php_admin_value session.cache_limiter nocache

            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
    ErrorDocument 402 /errors/402.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /errors/405.html
    ErrorDocument 406 /errors/406.html
    ErrorDocument 407 /errors/407.html
    ErrorDocument 408 /errors/408.html
    ErrorDocument 409 /errors/409.html
    ErrorDocument 410 /errors/410.html
    ErrorDocument 411 /errors/411.html
    ErrorDocument 412 /errors/412.html
    ErrorDocument 413 /errors/413.html
    ErrorDocument 414 /errors/414.html
    ErrorDocument 415 /errors/415.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
    ErrorDocument 501 /errors/501.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /errors/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /errors/503.html
    ErrorDocument 504 /errors/504.html
    ErrorDocument 505 /errors/505.html

    ServerSignature Off
    LogLevel error

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.com
    RewriteCond /var/vhosts/%2/www/%1 -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

That shows use of quite a few settings including setting some php settings.